# S3 client partially uploads .png files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, png, boto3

I am developing a Python app which consist of an uploading module, the core function pulls .png images from a queue, and by using a Boto3 client, uploading them to a certain bucket.

The problem is that sometimes, not always, the images are only partially uploaded. e.g. when I download a defective image, it seem to be cropped.

When I manually uploading the images (using an FTP/SSH client) the images are being perfectly uploaded.

The following is my core function, note that I'm using `upload_fileobj()` with a callback for progress bar mechanics.

```py
def upload_file_aws(self):
   s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key,
                              aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_key)
            if (not self.uploader.queue.empty()):
                file = self.uploader.queue.get()
                with open(file, 'rb') as f:
                    aws_format = '%s' % AppObject.file_path_dic.get(file) 
                    s3.upload_fileobj(f, self.bucket_name, aws_format, Callback=ProgressBarInit(file))
```

Did anyone encountered with that problem before?
At Amazon's doc file they declare that boto3 protocols does not enables partial uploads.

Answer (score 1):

There are high chances that it is happening for larger images of size more then `5 MB`.
You should be using `multipart` `upload` for `larg`e `size` objects.

Here is basic code example of `multipart` upload.

```
import boto3

def upload_file( filename ):
    session = boto3.Session()
    s3_client = session.client( 's3' )

    try:
        print "Uploading file:", filename

        tc = boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig()
        t = boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer( client=s3_client, 
                                         config=tc )

        t.upload_file( filename, 'my-bucket-name', 'name-in-s3.dat' )

    except Exception as e:
        print "Error uploading: %s" % ( e )
```

Comment: Thanks!
is this method support callbacks?